# Android setOnTouchListener fires over child button

Tags: android, event-handling, touch

Hello i have View.

```
content = this.getChildAt(1);
```

I apply setOnTouchListener

```
    content.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return MainLayout.this.onContentTouch(v, event);
        }
    });
```

If View contains no buttons or clickable elements it's OK.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Layout 1"
    android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when View contains for example buttons nothing happens when i drag button.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/wrapper"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#008000"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/someTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Layout2"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnUploadImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnUpload"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/btn_bg"
    android:onClick="UploadImgs"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="@string/btnUploadToServer"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to fire View setOnTouchListener on button drag and also I want to fire click event when I click on button.

KInd regards.